# Native Unable to Receive Message using EasyNDK Cocos2d-x

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x, message

I am trying to send message from *C++ class* say **TestingCPP** to *Objective C++ wrapper* class , say **WrapperClass (inherited from NSObject)** using **EasyNDK** in cocos2dx. But strangely, wrapper class cannot receive any message. But if I try to receive message in **rootViewController (Parent : UIViewController)**, it can receive messages!

I think receiver can be of any type since method parameter is of type `NSObject`.

```
+ (void) SetNDKReciever:(NSObject*)reciever;
```

So I am wondering why my wrapper class cannot receive message? May be I am missing something or I am wrong. Please clear me out. Thanks.

**Code:**

**TestingCPP.cpp**

```
void TestingLib::sendMessageToNative(cocos2d::CCString *message)
{
    CCDictionary* prms = CCDictionary::create();
    prms->setObject(message, "str");

    SendMessageWithParams(string("receiverAtNative"),prms);
}
```

**WrapperClass.mm**

```
- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {

        [IOSNDKHelper SetNDKReciever:instance];

    }
    return self;
}

-(void) receiverAtNative:(NSObject *) message
{

NSLog(@"!!! Message received");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think @iAnum, you have replaced self to instance in Obj-C on line :

[IOSNDKHelper SetNDKReciever:instance];

try changing it to

[IOSNDKHelper SetNDKReciever:self];

For proper usage please try : http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/How_to_work_on_iOS_-_C++Objective-C

Comment: thanks for reply. Actually, `instance` is singleton instance pointing to the current object.

Comment: Can you post your error description as well as code location from where the error is raised? Thanks.